# How to undo a git push -u origin my_branch?

Tags: git, version-control

I used the following command to send my local git commit to the server:

```
git push -u origin my_bransh
```

How to undo this push?

Answer (score 2):

You just delete the remote reference

```
git push origin :my_branch
```

or with the current syntax

```
git push --delete origin mybranch
```

You'll also have to prune the local tracking branch from the local repo with

```
git remote prune origin
```

or as suggested by cupcake in the comments below,

```
git fetch -p
```

Comment: It's more typical nowadays to prune remote-tracking branches with `git fetch -p`, but this answer is correct nonetheless.